# Collision function calls before colliding

Tags: box2d, cocos2d, cocos2d-x

My Box2D contact listener class is calling post solve and beginning the contact function before colliding? This is causing my object to bounce back before hitting the ground. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is to assume the body's visual representation (ie sprite) matches the actual body shape.

Common causes for getting this wrong:

- Box2D rectangle shape uses center and half-width and half-height of the resulting rect shape. Same with circle which is initialized with radius, not diameter.
- Pixels/Point to meter conversion not or incorrectly applied.
- Shape not centered on the visual. For example not all rendering engines put the sprite's position at the center, some have position at a corner of the rectangle respectively in all engines one can change this anchor point. This will only offset the sprite, but not the body shape.

Tip: enable Box2D debug drawing to see if your shapes match expectations.

Comment: i applied drawing and it clearly shows that body begin contact call before colliding and i am using PTM 24

Comment: perhaps a polygon skin issue? there may be a tiny gap between bodies, see the box2d manual ( chapter 4 i believe) for an explanation of this behavior

Comment: but is there any solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: thanks to you i do some research on polygon skin issue and change its value so then i get my desire result but i want to ask that it is good that i change value from 0.005 to my desired value